# A few questions about php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

How can I retrieve the result from the `$avatar` array?
This is what I tried:
I want to get the following(url):
code:

```
<div id="fotoprofilo"><img src="http://images.instagram.com/profiles/profile_19347213_75sq_0000.jpg"></div>
```

And php:

```
$s2 = file_get_contents("http://followgram.me/user");
    $avatar = "";
     preg_match_all('/fotoprofilo\s*"><img src=".*\b">/', $s2, $avatar);
    print_r($avatar[0]);
```

1) How is the result working?
2) Will it find it? (**Because I can't seem to see the value**)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/112968)

Comment: Also, your server must be configured to allow file_get_contents to retrieve files over http://, per default it only works with local files

Comment: #knittl It actually works for me :) (the http), I am checking the don't use... Plus, how does the result work?!

Comment: I agree with knittl - Use one of the **perfectly good XML/HTML parsers** out there

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and brackets for subexpressions:

```
$s2 = file_get_contents("http://followgram.me/user");
$avatar = array();
preg_match_all('/fotoprofilo\s*"><img src="(.*)">/', $s2, $avatar);
print_r($avatar);
```

$avatar[1] should contain your URL.

To test regex and preg_match_all you can use http://reghex.mgvmedia.com/. Choose "PHP" as language and check option "global search". Works fine :)